# R: How would I remove the values in the bottom right half of a square so that the result is a triangle?

Tags: r

If I have DF1 as such:

```
a <- c(5,10,15)
b <- c(5,10,15)
c <- c(5,10,15)
DF1 <- data.frame(a,b,c)
DF1

   a  b  c
1  5  5  5
2 10 10 10
3 15 15 15
```

How would I remove the bottom right half of the square such that the result looks like:

```
   a  b  c
1  5  5  5
2 10 10 NA
3 15 NA NA
```

Answer (score 3):

Reversing column indices of `lower.tri`:

```
DF1[lower.tri(DF1)[,ncol(DF1):1]] <- NA
DF1
#>    a  b  c
#> 1  5  5  5
#> 2 10 10 NA
#> 3 15 NA NA
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit hacky, but in essence you want to use the function `lower.tri` and mirror the resulting matrix. I've wrote a function `lower.tri.right` which does exactly that.

```
a <- c(5,10,15)
b <- c(5,10,15)
c <- c(5,10,15)
x <- data.frame(a,b,c)
lower.tri.right <- function(x, repl = NA, diag = FALSE){
  tmp <- lower.tri(x)
  tmp <- tmp[,ncol(tmp):1]
  x[tmp] <- repl
  return(x)
}
lower.tri.right(x)

   c  b  a
1  5  5  5
2 10 10 NA
3 15 NA NA
```

With this solution, you can choose to convert the diagonal aswell and you can choose what to use as the replacement (repl).

Answer (score 0):

I`m sure there is a more clean and elegant way but this will do the job

```
a <- c(5,10,15)
b <- c(5,10,15)
c <- c(5,10,15)

DF1 <- data.frame(a,b,c)

  a  b  c
1  5  5  5
2 10 10 10
3 15 15 15

len <- ncol(DF1)

for (i in 2:nrow(DF1)){
 DF1[i,][len:ncol(DF1)] <- NA
 len <- len - 1
}

> DF1
   a  b  c
1  5  5  5
2 10 10 NA
3 15 NA NA
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it explicitly by asking for the exact element positions to be set to `NA`:

`DF1[2, 3] = DF1[3, 2] = DF1[3, 3] = NA`

Output:

```
   a  b  c
1  5  5  5
2 10 10 NA
3 15 NA NA
```

Or, if the directionality of your matrix object (`DF1`) is open to change, you can better do this using the `lower.tri` function as follows:

`DF1[lower.tri(DF1)] <- NA`

Output:

```
   a  b  c
1  5  5  5
2 NA 10 10
3 NA NA 15
```

Comment: This does not produce a lower right triangle matrix as requested by OP.

Comment: @Nico I know, that's why I mentioned it as a possibility if their matrix/data was open to a direction change as it would be easier.